# Get data from neo4j

Tags: scala, neo4j, cypher

I am writing code to retreive data  from neo4j using scala. My code is as follows:

```
def getData(type: String): mutable.Buffer[String] = {
    val driver  = getDriverInsatnce()
    val session = driver.session
      val query=
        s"""
           |MATCH (a:$type)
           |RETURN a.Id as Id
           |""".stripMargin

      val result = session.run(query)
      val Ids= result.list().asScala.map(s => s.get("Id").asString())
    session.close()
    return Ids
  }
```

It gives me result sometimes. Means it  returns Id sometimes but sometime it returns Empty ArrayBuffer(). How can I correct it?

Comment: You may want to give a look to higher-level libraries like [**neotypes**](https://neotypes.github.io/neotypes/).

Comment: I can see my code fetches result everytime from neo4j it is just  "result.list().asScala.map(s => s.get("Id").asString())" code which is sometimes giving empty ArrayBuffer()

Comment: Since the `type` argument passed to `getData()` is used as the label of the `a` node in the `MATCH` clause, the Cypher query is *supposed to* return no result whenever the DB has no nodes having the specified label.

Comment: I can see DB has node with specified type